# How to return a specific Json in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using this plugin http://devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/ to autocomplete like Facebook Style. I'm just a bit confuse on how to return the Json result that fits the plugin's need.

The json result must be like this:

```
[[1, 'John', null, ''],[2,'Mary', null, ''],[3,'Mark', null, '']]
```

The problem is when I return the result to my View:

```
return Json(myjSon, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is the result:

```
"[[1, \u0027John\u0027, null, \u0027\u0027],[2, \u0027Maryn\u0027, null, \u0027\u0027],[3, \u0027Mark\u0027, null, \u0027\u0027]]"
```

The aposthrophe was converted to \u0027  and its ruining my code. What should I do?

Comment: can you clarify the type of "myjSon" object that you are returning to your view.

Answer (score 3):

You just did wrong type of myjSon, which should be an object not string.

```
var myjSon = new[]{
    new object[]{1,"John", null, ""},
    new object[]{2,"Mary", null, ""},
    new object[]{3,"Mark", null, ""}
};
return Json(myjSon, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

EDIT: code corrected according to the comments

Comment: Hi Dennis, I tried exactly what you said but I got this error message: No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Comment: It complains about the new[] inside the main new[] { .... }; Can you help me with that please? Thanks!

Comment: @Guillermo change the inner `new []` to `new object[]` and that should work. The compiler is complaining because you have strings and ints in the array and it doesn't know which type to use